# What is the best way to apply the log-sum-exp trick in this situation?

Tags: particle-filter, numerics

I am aware of the "log-sum-exp" trick for calculating the logarithm of sums that handles overflow and underflow issues. However, I would like to know more about how it works. In particular, I am wondering: *what is the most numerically precise way to evaluate the following expression using the "log-sum-exp" trick?*

The expression I am concerned with this the following:

$$
\log\left[\sum_i \left(\frac{a^i }{\sum_j a^j}\right) \left(\frac{b^i }{\sum_k b^k} \right)\right],
$$
where $i$ and $j$ are indices, not powers.

Instead of having $\{a^i\}$ and $\{b^i\}$, I have their logarithms. As you can see, there are several ways to apply this rule-of-thumb. Here are a few.

### 1. The all-together way

$$
m + \log\left[\sum_i \exp\left\{ \log a^i + \log b^i - \log\sum_ja^j - \log\sum_k b^k - m \right\}\right]
$$
where $m = \max_i\{ \log a^i + \log b^i - \log\sum_ja^j - \log\sum_k b^k  \}$ and we could apply the log-sum-exp technique to the inner sums as well, which would be used for both calculating the maximum $m_1$, and for calculating the outer sum over $i$.

### 2. The split-up way:

You could also split up the thing into products like $\log\sum_i a^ib^i - \log \sum_j a^j - \log \sum_k b^k$, and use the trick on each of the three terms:

\begin{align*}
&m_1 + \log\sum_i \exp [\log a^i + \log b^i - m_1] \\
&- m_2 - \log\sum_j\exp[\log a^j - m_2] \\
&- m_3 -\log \sum_k\exp[ \log b^k - m_3].
\end{align*}

### 3. The straightforward way:

Don't do any of this. Just exponentiate everything, get $\{a^i\}$ and $\{b^i\}$, and compute the original expression.

Answer (score 1):

So, the sum terms in the denominator are invariant, over each of the terms in the outer sum, since you're always summing over all $j$ in the denominator sums.

Then, what you want to do probably is make sure that the largest of the terms in the outer sum is reasonably representable, e.g. if it equals $1$, that probably meets our requirements.

The numerator is not combinatorial in the number of terms, but is linear in values of $i$, i.e. it's:

$$
\exp(a_1)\exp(b_1) + \exp(a_2)\exp(b_2) + \dots \\
= \exp(a_1 + b_1) + \exp(a_2 + b_2) + \dots
$$

(where I'm writing $\exp(a_i)$ to mean your $a^i$, since I want to make the exponentials explicit).

So, to make sure the outer sum has $1$ as its maximum numerator, we can determine $\max_i(a_i +  b_i)$, and divide by the exponential of that.

Let:

$$
E = \max_i(a_i + b_i)
$$

Then we'd calculate:

$$
\log \left(
    \sum_i \left(
          \frac{\exp(a_i)\exp(b_i)/\exp(E)}
             {\left(\sum_j \exp(a_j) \sum_j(\exp(b_j))\right) / \exp(E)}
    \right)
\right)
$$

$$
= \log \left(
    \sum_i \left(
          \frac{\exp(a_i + b_i - \max_i(a_i + b_i))}
             {\left(\sum_j \exp(a_j) \sum_j(\exp(b_j))\right)/\exp(\max_i(a_i + b_i))}
    \right)
\right)
$$

What to do with the $\exp(\max_i(a_i + b_i))$ term in the denominator?

So, let's determine:

$$
i' = \arg \max_i(a_i + b_i)
$$

Then $E = a_{i'} + b_{i'}$. And our expression becomes:

$$
= \log \left(
    \sum_i \left(
          \frac{\exp(a_i + b_i - \max_i(a_i + b_i))}
             {\left(\sum_j \exp(a_j) \sum_j(\exp(b_j))\right)/\exp(a_{i'} + b_{i'})}
    \right)
\right)
$$

$$
= \log \left(
    \sum_i \left(
          \frac{\exp(a_i + b_i - \max_i(a_i + b_i))}
             {\left(\sum_j \exp(a_j) \sum_j(\exp(b_j))\right)\exp(-a_{i'})\exp(-b_{i'})}
    \right)
\right)
$$

and then we can just multiply the exponential sum of $a_j$ in the denominator by $\exp(-a_{i'})$, and the same for the exponential sum of $b_j$. So we have:

$$
\log \left(
    \sum_i \left(
          \frac{\exp(a_i + b_i - \max_i(a_i + b_i))}
             {\left(\sum_j \exp(a_j - a_{i'}) \sum_j(\exp(b_j - b_{i'}))\right)}
    \right)
\right)
$$

and since we've determined $i'$ anyway, we could if we want rewrite the numerator slightly:

$$
= \log \left(
    \sum_i \left(
          \frac{\exp(a_i - a_{i'} + b_i - b_{i'}))}
             {\left(\sum_j \exp(a_j - a_{i'}) \sum_j(\exp(b_j - b_{i'}))\right)}
    \right)
\right)
$$

This expression will give small numerical error, since the largest numerator will be exactly 1, neither under nor overflowing. Other numerators will all be smaller than this, and not overflow.

Comment: could you say a little more about why you didn't split it up further?

Comment: What do you mean by 'split it up further'? Which bit are you thinking about splitting? Do you mean, why dont I treat the fraction in $a_*$ and the fraction in $b_*$ separately?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $a_*$ because you haven't used this notation yet. I am talking about pulling out the denominator (inside the the outer sum). Then the expression becomes the log of a fraction, which is equivalent to log of a sum minus the log of the product of those two sums (which could also be further split up). This is discussed in my question.